# How to calculate the theoretical max UPI bandwidth of a Linux dual-socket machine?

Tags: performance, x86, intel, numa, memory-bandwidth

I want to calculate the theoretical UPI bandwidth of a dual-socket machine running Linux system in order to estimate the max remote memory access bandwidth.

Theoretically, UPI bandwidth = UPI speed (GT/s) * bit width * link num * 2

**I want to know how I can obtain these parameters without rebooting the machine.**

The cpu of the server is Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 6230R * 2, the OS is CentOS 7.